# IllegalMonitorStateException Java Android

Tags: java, android

```
Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Movie m = adapter.getItem(id);
        m.setTitle(title);

        View v = listView.getChildAt(id);
        if (v != null) {
            ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            if (p != null)
                p.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.notify();
    }
};

synchronized (runner) {
    runOnUiThread(runner);

    try {
        runner.wait();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

}
```

This code above causes a crash. I don't know why. It is supposed to run on the ui thread so i can disable the progressbars and update the movie information. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know why.

You didn't provide a stack trace, but I *assume* it's on the call to `this.notify()`.

From the documentation of [`Object.notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--):

> Throws:
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

In other words, you'd need:

```
synchronized (this) {
    this.notify();
}
```

*Always* look at the stack trace for an exception, and always consult the documentation to see if it exlpains why you're getting the exception.